# Error while minifing JS with regular expression in asp.net bundling

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-bundling

I am getting the error below while bundling JS files in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application

/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(3828,34-35): run-time error JS1013: Syntax error in regular expression: .
(3789,41-42): run-time error JS1013: Syntax error in regular expression: .

The regular expression at 3828 is

```
function formatPhoneNumber(value) {
       value = value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
       return value;
}
```

at 3789

```
var isValid = /^[0-9,.$-\s\n]*$/.test(value);
```

Both expressions are working fine, but not sure why bundling cannot minify them

**Update 1**
common.js has the regular expressions

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.extensions.js",
                "~/Scripts/common.js",
                "~/Scripts/format.js"));
```

and in _layout.cshtml

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

Comment: Can you provide included script names inside `RegisterBundles`? I assume that all regex above used inside custom JS file, if its debug version works perfectly but can't be minified it's possible that script mappings messing up.

Comment: Please check my update1

Comment: Please check that you are using the latest available version of MVC 5 (update NuGet packages, perhaps even update Visual Studio if that's what you are using).

Comment: i am using VS 2017 and Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization v 1.1.3 which is the latest at this moment

Answer (score 0):

I found it
There was no issue with the formatPhoneNumber. However there was issue with `isValid` regular expression. The error was `You can not create a range with a shorthand escape sequences`

So  I replaced `/^[0-9,.$-\s\n]*$/`
 with `/^[0-9,.$\-\s\n]*$/`

https://regex101.com/ very helpful. Actually shows the error message.